# Program Algorithmic time

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, analysis-of-algorithms

Just a simple question to get the total time to do a particular program or calculate Big O of the function

Lets say I have an n x n array

x = 0, y = 0

for i = z to n:

x = i + 1

y = i - 1

C[i][i] = C[x][y]

next i

Ignoring the actual way the program run, just thought of it on the fly. 
My question is for the cost of time to run this, is it just (n-z+1)*2

2 from (addition and subtraction)

(n-z+1) for number of instance/iterations of the for loop

do you count also the array substitution as well, hence its (n-z+1)*3?

Comment: "for i to n" is meaningless. Please fix.

Comment: Stating a cost as a function of $i$ doesn't make sense. $i$ doesn't have a unique value, it evolves as the program is running.

Comment: Also note that this code causes illegal accesses to the array.

Comment: @Yves thanks for the comments, all fixed

Comment: You did not fix the illegal accesse(s).

Comment: To tell you the truth I don't even know what that is, not sure what to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i= 1 to n -> 1 for
  x= i-1 -> 1 -, 1 =
  y= i+1 -> 1 +, 1 =
  c[i][i]= c[x][y] -> 2 [][], 1 =
endfor
```

I have tried to annotate the code with "costs". `for` denotes the cost of one loop iteration (increment and exit test); `=` denotes a variable assignment; `[][]` denotes indexing of a 2D array.

The loop is executed exactly `n` times, and the accounting gives

```
n for, n +, n -, 3n =, 2n [][]
```

It actually makes no sense to add up these terms and conclude `8n` operations as we don't know if the costs are equal. In reality, they are not, they are not even constant, they are highly architecture-dependent, and we can't even know them precisely.

All we can reasonably say is that the running time will be approximately proportional to `n`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! What you said make sense that the end result should be proportional to n, I can also relate it to say that this function $f is O(n)$. But from the textbook I read "Discrete Math by Susanna 4th edition page 742" it gives the addition and multiplication with a value of 1 each. and then ultimately consider them as a constant and result in proprotionally to n. So I was thinking to do the steps did in the textbook for when there is indexing, but not sure whether indexing count as 1, but maybe like you said, its arbitrary.

Comment: @DSt_FTW: of course I cannot guess what you saw in the book. For pedagogical purposes some authors use such simplifications. The key word is *proportionality*. Exact values are out of reach.

Comment: noted. thanks. I guess I will just assume something as long as the end is correct as you said.